# Exactly what a Thread Pool in Java doing?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Thread Pool like any ExecutorServices, we defined a newFixedPool of size 3. Now I have a queue of around 10000 runnable tasks.
For executing the above process I have these doubts -

1. To execute the above process , is the executor will let only 3 threads from the queus of tasks to run in one shot?
2. The Pool will be carrying 3 Threads , and those 3 threads will only be responsible for executing all the 10000 tasks. If it is correct , how a single thread is running different runnable tasks as finally those tasks are as well threads itself , and in the mid  of the running of any of the job/tasks , you can assign new responsibility to the Pool Thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, at most only 3 threads will be in the pool at once if in fact you are using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3)`
2. The 10,000 tasks are not `Threads` they are simply `Runnables`. A `Thread` has to be started via `Thread#start` to actually create a system thread. Tasks (instances of `Runnable`) are placed in a `BlockingQueue`. Threads from the thread pool will poll the BlockingQueue for a task to run. When they complete the task, they return to the queue to get another. If more tasks are added, then they are inserted into the `BlockingQueue` according to the rules of the implementation of that queue. For most queues this is First-In-First-Out, but a `PriorityQueue` actually uses a `Comparator` or natural ordering to sort tasks as they are inserted.

Answer (score 0):

**Below is customThreadPool in java which accept noofThreads and MaxConcurrentTask.
Also it has stop() to stop complete ThreadPool**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;


@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class ThreadPool { 


    private BlockingQueue taskQueue = null;  
    private List<PoolThread> threads = new ArrayList<PoolThread>(); 
    private boolean isStopped = false; 

    public ThreadPool(int noOfThreads, int maxNoOfTasks) { 
        taskQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue(maxNoOfTasks);
        for(int i=0; i<noOfThreads; i++) {    
            threads.add(new PoolThread(taskQueue));  
        }   

        for(PoolThread thread : threads) {    
            thread.start();  
        }  
    }  

    public synchronized void execute(Runnable task) {  

        if(this.isStopped) 
            throw  new IllegalStateException("ThreadPool is stopped");

        this.taskQueue.offer(task); 
    }  

    public synchronized void stop() {  
        this.isStopped = true;  
        for(PoolThread thread : threads)    {     
            thread.stopMe();   
        } 
    }
}


@SuppressWarnings("all")
class PoolThread extends Thread { 

    private BlockingQueue taskQueue = null; 
    private boolean       isStopped = false; 
    public PoolThread(BlockingQueue queue)  { 
        taskQueue = queue; 
    } 

    public void run()   {   
        while(!isStopped()) {   
            try {    
                Runnable runnable = (Runnable) taskQueue.poll();  
                runnable.run();     
            } catch(Exception e)    {    
                //log or otherwise report exception,        //but keep pool thread alive.  

            }    
        } 
    } 

    public synchronized void stopMe()   {  
        isStopped = true;   
        this.interrupt(); 
        //break pool thread out of dequeue() call. 
    }  

    public synchronized boolean isStopped() {  
        return isStopped;  
    }
}
```